# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values , but only one is allowed

Tags: .net-core

I got the above error when i call .net core api from backbone js
Here is my code

in start up.cs:

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

in Configure i do the following:-

```
   app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");      
   app.UseStaticFiles();      
   ConfigureAuth(app);       
   app.UseMvc();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i try to removing ALL code that enabled CORS and then added the cors settings to the system.webServer node of my Web.Config but issue still exists

Comment: I think when you use `.AllowCredentials()`, you need to specify domains, can't use `.AllowAnyOrigin()`. I'm removing backbone because it doesn't have anything to do with the problem, it's a backend issue

Comment: i fixed the issue. remove header from iis  http response headers